# Validate input and Insert picklist value through process builder

Tags: process-builder, picklist

I have a custom object called transaction__c with picklist field called status with value Yes and No.

But the input for the picklist(status) is coming as 0 and 1 from external API.
For this reason I am trying before insertion to execute process builder to convert the value as '0' to 'No' and '1' to 'Yes'.

Could some one guide me how to proceed further.

Comment: How are the records being inserted? Direct connection to the REST or SOAP API? A custom Apex REST service? Data Loader?

Comment: Hi David, Records are inserted through data loader.

Answer (score 0):

The Apex Data Loader already understands '0' as false and '1' as true when importing to Checkbox fields. See page 10 of the [Data Loader Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf).

The easiest solution in one sense would be to replace your picklist field with a checkbox, since it's only representing true/false values. Then you could import to it directly. However, if that's not an option, you can create a Checkbox field on your `Transaction__c` object and load the 0/1 data to that field. Then, use a Workflow Rule or Process Builder to update the picklist value based upon the checkbox.

You can configure a Process Builder to run on record creation only and update your picklist(s) using a formula based on their current values. The `CASE()` function will likely be useful for this purpose. Please note, however, that this solution will become messy if you're using restricted picklists, as you'll need to retain all of the possible values (pre- and post-transformation) in your picklist value sets.

Based on your comments, it sounds like you have a lot of transformation and/or data cleaning to do as these records are coming in. You may want to look at adopting an ETL solution, as this type of workflow is what that software is intended to do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Replacement is not possible as it is live data and other option by adding additional checkbox field is possible.                  
But there are few more picklist values which needs to be validated and changed. For ex, other picklist field(city__c) value was stored as LA. But input is coming as 'Los Angeles'. And also this is required for live synchronization not an one time migration. So doing manually is not possible. Is there a way to achieve through process builder?

Answer (score 0):

You can write workflow rule or process builder to assign  '0' to 'No' and '1' to 'Yes' during insertion, but for uploading bulk data volume we use to deactivate triggers or workflow rules or processes. So, check the consequences.

It is advisable to insert the data in proper format during insertion. That is data transformation should be done outside of Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you Santanu for the suggestion. I will check for the alternative option.